# A way to import rounded launcher icon in Android Studio 2.4 Preview 5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.4

Android project structure shows two launcher icon types. One is squared launcher icons and rounded launcher icons.

[image]

It is possible to add rounded launcher icon manually by copying the rounded launcher icon to respective folders. But is there a hidden way to add the icon images using **New -> Image Asset** option.

[image]

[image]

I know it is possible to do it manually. But I am wondering whether there is another way.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean icon type in Image asset screen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe round the corners of the imported image, then after import to android studio, copy files to their respective location.